# Downvotes history

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

In Stack overflow you can browse your reputation history at `tab=reputation`.

But I don't think it includes reputation lost to downvotes. I am asking this because my reputation has decreased by 2 points last night and I cannot figure out why.

Maybe when I was using my tablet, which I am not very comfortable with, I downvoted some posts without noticing it.

Is there a downvote history tab? If not, I think it would be a good idea implementing one, and make it easier to remove your downvotes once someone edits his questions or answers.

Comment: I am guessing you had a suggested edit on a post that was deleted.  Do you have "show removed posts" checked?

Comment: Reputation changes for downvotes **do** show in the reputation tab.

Comment: @JohnPalmer, thanks! I have been missing this all this time. I checked it and it turns out you are right. Maybe it is better to move this "option" in a more visible area.

Comment: Actually, a way to view posts you downvoted that were recently edited isn't a bad idea....

Comment: Your recent -2 came from a post being deleted which you had [previously edited for +2](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12420445/revisions)

Comment: Yeah @AndrewBarber, thank you! I did not check "show removed posts" option and there were no way to know it. Now I get it.

Comment: @LazyNinja Are you looking for downvotes you've given or downvotes you've received?

Comment: @WendiKidd didn't that suggestion pop up on ELL or ELU too recently ? I know I saw it *SomeStackWhere* :)) +1 on the notion as it would help us learn from our own voting habits over time. ... maybe even to reconsider a vote, and revote etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You lost two points from the suggested edit that you proposed back in November on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420445/is-it-possible-to-use-google-mapview-with-using-my-custom-bitmap).

You can see reputation changes caused by removed posts by checking the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of the reputation tab.

Answer (score 8):

The *Votes* tab in your profile allows you to view your down-votes. Click on the *Votes* tab, then you can filter by *All*, *Upvote*, ***Downvote***, ...